# ¿Como quito los .spltis a este código, para que lea entrada y salida sin espacios?

Tags: java, condiciones, bucles, estructuras-de-datos, split

necesito quitar los .splits a este código que encontré en Google, este es un problema de pasar Infijo a PostFijo, pero la verdad no se manejar muy bien los .splits y hay cosas que no comprendo por lo que arruino el código cuando lo cambio, quisiera ayuda para cambiar este código.

El código lee el string asi: "A / 3 + c - d ) / 2"
y arroga el resultado así:  "A 3 / c + d - 2 / "

lo que quiero es leer así el string: "A/3+c-d)/2"
y quiero que salga así: "A3/c+d-2/"

Este es mi código, agradecería que me ayudaran, y por favor se que es muy tonto pero no se hacerlo y tampoco me cierren mi pregunta pls

```
 import java.util.Stack;

 class Main {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
 String infix = "( A / 3 + c - d ) / 2";  // como leo esto asi sin espacios "(A/3+c-d)/2";
 System.out.println("infix: " + infix);
 System.out.println("postfix: " + infixToPostfix(infix));
 }


 private static String infixToPostfix(String infix) {
 /* To find out the precedence, we take the index of the


   token in the ops string and divide by 2 (rounding down).
This will give us: 0, 0, 1, 1, 2 */
final String ops = "-+/*^";
 
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<>();
 
for (String token : infix.split("\\s")) {
if (token.isEmpty())
continue;
char c = token.charAt(0);
int idx = ops.indexOf(c);
 
// check for operator
if (idx != -1) {
if (s.isEmpty())
s.push(idx);
 
else {
while (!s.isEmpty()) {
int prec2 = s.peek() / 2;
int prec1 = idx / 2;
if (prec2 > prec1 || (prec2 == prec1 && c != '^'))
sb.append(ops.charAt(s.pop())).append(' ');
else break;
}
s.push(idx);
}
}
else if (c == '(') {
s.push(-2); // -2 stands for '('
}
else if (c == ')') {
// until '(' on stack, pop operators.
while (s.peek() != -2)
sb.append(ops.charAt(s.pop())).append(' ');
    s.pop();

}
else {
sb.append(token).append(' ');
}
}
while (!s.isEmpty())
sb.append(ops.charAt(s.pop())).append(' ');
return sb.toString();
}
}
```

Comment: en resumen quieres mover los caracteres *especiales*  a la derecha (+1)

Comment: Que, ¿Como asi?, lo unico que quiero ingresar los datos sin espacios y que me arroge el resultado sin espacios, no es mas, como hago esto, este codigo lo encontre en google y no he podido modificar lo que mencione.

Comment: si quieres que el texto quede sin espacios la respuesta que te dieron es correcta, de lo contrario podrías ser mas especifico en lo que quieres

Comment: pero falta modificar la entrada, para que al ingresar SIN ESPACIOS el texto arroge el resultado, como lo hago.

Comment: Osea quieres que el usuario ingrese la palabra **SIN ESPACIOS** y el programa quite los espacios espacios a la palabra?

Comment: Si, algo asi pero el programa principal es pasar de infijo a postfijo

Comment: ok entonces solo lee la entrada del usuario y dependiendo de eso haces la operacion

Comment: lo que quiero es leer así el string:(inpunt): "A/3+c-d)/2" y quiero que salga así (output) "A3/c+d-2/"

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124344/discussion-between-christian-and-karlosandres).

Comment: El programa lee el string con ESPACIOS y Yo quiero LEER el strinng SIN ESPACIOS, yo creo que no es difícil comprender lo quiero, deberias leer el enunciado de mi problema.

Comment: Por favor usa el chat, los comentarios no son utilizados para debates extensos

Answer (score 0):

Al obtener el valor en tu mètodo simplemente elimina los espacios en blanco usando `replaceAll()` en tu cadena:

```
  ...
  return sb.toString().replaceAll("\\s+","");
  ...
```

de esta forma tu programa tendrà como salida el formato deseado:

```
postfix: A3/c+d-2/
```

Comment: Como hago para la entrada sin los ingresar espacios?, si se hace asi me da java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException, que significa  "\\s+"?

Comment: Hola @karlosandres "\\s+" es una expresión regular (REGEX) que indica espacios en blanco, lo que se realiza aquí es que convierte los espacios en blanco en cadenas vacias "". Ok veo que lo que deseas es ingresar "A/3+c-d)/2" para obtener la salida, veo que ahora esto entonces no funcionaría for (String token : infix.split("\\s")) {

Comment: Si quito el for entonces como quedaria el codigo?